# Admin and non-admin authentication in Laravel 4

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel-4, admin

I want to have an authentication for Admin and for Non-admin. I'm having the admin infromation in 'users' db table, and non-admin information in 'customers' table.
How to use Laravel's Auth class to create authentication for this two different user roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for starter you should merge the two tables and then define a new column named "role_id" and then a new table called "roles" then as you attempt like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
    {
        Session::put('role',  Auth::user()->role_id);
        return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    }
```

then via Session you can get the role whenever it's needed and decide to whatever yo want to do with it...
note: also edit your User model so role_id can be accessible
happy coding